# how tcl handle square bracket in the regexp output?

Tags: regex, string, tcl

I try to use regular expression command like:

```
IN: regexp -all -inline {\S+} "RR\[0\] in"
OUT:{RR[0]} in
```

But,when there is no square bracket in the string,the output format is different.

```
IN: regexp -all -inline {\S+} "RR in"
OUT:RR in
```

Why does the first element is between curly braces in the first case?

Comment: Are you asking about the square brackets or the curly braces you see in the list returned by the first command?

Comment: Sorry. I am asking why does the first element need curly braces in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the square brackets are reserved in tcl for executing commands.

So it evaluate every square brackets found, included those inside strings delimited by *"*.

So when it returns the regexp matching it put the curling brackets to protect the string to be interpreted as containing a command.

Even that, the results continue to be a string.

For example if you do that:

```
% set r [regexp -all -inline {\S+} "RR\[0\] in"]
{RR[0]} in
```

And then you print from a loop:

```
% foreach x $r { puts $x }
RR[0]
in
```

By the *join* command you could easily convert any kind of list into a string when you need, avoiding to remove the brackets with trim functions.

```
% puts [join $r ]
RR[0] in
```

or direct to the element:

```
% puts [join [lindex $r 0] ]
RR[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an error when you run the regexp the way it is. It should be:

```
regexp -all -inline {\S+} {RR[0] in}
```

With braces around the string you search in. Because the square barckets are interpreted as a command, if you must tell tcl not to make a substitution, and one of the ways to tell it is by using braces.

Saying that, when the brackets do not exist, the regexp won't find them, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I mean "RR\[0\] in" in the first case. Why does the first element need curly braces in the first case